# Obtener datos de un arreglo con LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

si arrRep es un arreglo puedo realizar la siguiente consulta con linq son el arreglo arrRep, quiero las referencias que cumplan la condición de la consulta:

```
arrRep = oRep.buscarTodosImpo(dFecIni, dFecFin, nDato);

var q = (from f in arrRep
           where f.Arribo == "2017-01-01" || f.Revalidacion == "2017-01-01" || f.Previo == "2017-01-01" || f.Desadua == "2017-01-01" || f.EnvioFact == "2017-01-01"
                                 select f.Referencia).ToList();



public class ReporteGeneralImpo
{
    private string ejecutivo = "";

    public string Ejecutivo
    {
        get { return ejecutivo; }
        set { ejecutivo = value; }
    }
    private string referencia = "";

    public string Referencia
    {
        get { return referencia; }
        set { referencia = value; }
    }
    private string pedimento = "";

    public string Pedimento
    {
        get { return pedimento; }
        set { pedimento = value; }
    }
    private string tipoCarga = "";

    public string TipoCarga
    {
        get { return tipoCarga; }
        set { tipoCarga = value; }
    }
    private int tCont = 0;

    public int TCont
    {
        get { return tCont; }
        set { tCont = value; }
    }
    private string arribo;

    public string Arribo
    {
        get { return arribo; }
        set { arribo = value; }
    }
    private string revalidacion;

    public string Revalidacion
    {
        get { return revalidacion; }
        set { revalidacion = value; }
    }
    private string previo;

    public string Previo
    {
        get { return previo; }
        set { previo = value; }
    }
    private string desadua;

    public string Desadua
    {
        get { return desadua; }
        set { desadua = value; }
    }
    private string envioFact;

    public string EnvioFact
    {
        get { return envioFact; }
        set { envioFact = value; }
    }

    private string cliente = "";

    public string Cliente
    {
        get { return cliente; }
        set { cliente = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Saludos**

En lo personal prefiero usarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
var q = arrRep.Where(w => w.Arribo.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")=="2017-01-01"
            || w.Revalidacion.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")== "2017-01-01" 
            || w.Previo.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == "2017-01-01" 
            || w.Desadua.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == "2017-01-01" 
            || w.EnvioFact.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == "2017-01-01")
          .Select(s => s.Referencia).ToList();
```

Lo anterior asume que **Arribo**, **Revalidación** *....* son elementos tipo [Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx).

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Suerte.

> EDITADO

Respecto al error de *ToString* que mencionas se debe cada propiedad es un *String*; como desconocia los tipos de datos, por eso te coloque **Lo anterior asume que[...] son elementos tipo [Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx).**

Respecto al nuevo error que indicas de lo observado no encuentro que lo puede estar generando; deberás revisar de tu lado que lo ocasiona, al menos de lo que puse y veo tienes para filtrar los datos está correcto.
Si es al asignar a **var q =[.....];** u otra parte ve si puedes obtener más detalle del error que permita identificar su origen; en caso que el error no sea en **var q=....;** verifica el error (más detalles) puede deberse a un tratamiento que estes haciendo; recuerda que **q** (para tu caso) es básicamente un `List<string>` que puede estar vacío o tener 1 o más elementos.

Comment: Le quite el to String por que me marcaba error, lo ejecute y me salió el error System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: El conjunto de elementos representados por **arrRep** favor de proporcionar descripción (clase) como esta conformada para ver si puedo identificar el error (ya que con ello "se verían" los tipos de datos).

Comment: esta en la parte del controlador donde instancio la clase y creo el arreglo. ` ReporteGeneralImpo oRep = new ReporteGeneralImpo();
    ReporteGeneralImpo[] arrRep = null;`

Comment: ¿[public] class  ReporteGeneralImpo { / * Atributos y propiedades */  }? agregalo al planteamiento (no en los comentarios).

Comment: ya agregue la declaración de la clase y sus atributos